# MATLAB R2016b - MEX fails to compile C++ code

Tags: c++, matlab, mex, c++03

My [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57577372/updated-packages-now-mex-files-compiled-with-o0-are-invalid-mex-file) was cluttered with lots of information. Part of it was this problem, which hopefully on its own with more info will make more sense.

I am attempting to use `mex` in MATLAB R2016b to compile C++03 code on Windows.

When I try to do so, I get the following errors:

```
Error using mex
cpp_mexapi_version.o: In function `mexfilerequiredapiversion':
C:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2016b/extern/version/cpp_mexapi_version.cpp:4: multiple definition of `mexfilerequiredapiversion'
C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Temp\2\mex_53351148310745_8852\cpp_mexapi_version.obj:cpp_mexapi_version.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
myclass.o: In function `MyClass::MyClass(int, double*, int, int, int*, double, int, double, double, int, bool, char)':
C:\msys64\home\myName\Desktop\test/myclass.cpp:67: undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
C:\msys64\home\myName\Desktop\test/myclass.cpp:110: undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
C:\msys64\home\myName\Desktop\test/myclass.cpp:121: undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
myclass.o: In function `MyClass::MyClass(int, double*, int, int*, int, double, double, int, char)':
C:\msys64\home\myName\Desktop\test/myclass.cpp:139: undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
C:\msys64\home\myName\Desktop\test/myclass.cpp:178: undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
myclass.o:C:\msys64\home\myName\Desktop\test/myclass.cpp:189: more undefined references to `__imp___acrt_iob_func' follow
myclass.o: In function `MyAssertionClass::MyAssertionClass(char const*, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
C:\msys64\home\myName\Desktop\test/myclass.cpp:1014: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream()'
myclass.o: In function `MyAssertionClass::MyAssertionClass(char const*, int, char const*)':
C:\msys64\home\myName\Desktop\test/myclass.cpp:1029: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char,
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here's the verbose log from before it fails:

```
>> mex -v COMPFLAGS='$COMPFLAGS -std=c++03' -IC:\ourLibraryLocation myTargetMex.cpp myclass.o (a few other .o files here) cpp_mexapi_version.o
Verbose mode is on.
Neither -compatibleArrayDims nor -largeArrayDims is selected.
     Using -compatibleArrayDims. In the future, MATLAB will require the use of
     -largeArrayDims and remove the -compatibleArrayDims option.
     For more information:
     http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/upgrading-mex-files-to-use-64-bit-api.html.
... Looking for compiler 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'MW_MINGW64_LOC' ...Yes ('C:\TDM-GCC-64').
... Looking for file 'C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\g++.exe' ...Yes.
... Looking for folder 'C:\TDM-GCC-64' ...Yes.
Found installed compiler 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'.
Set PATH = C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\include\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\include;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\simulink\include;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\lib\win64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\avs\bin;C:\Program Files\avs\bin32;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Enterprise Vault\EVClient\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\bin;C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin;C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
Set INCLUDE = C:\TDM-GCC-64\include;C:\TDM-GCC-64\include;
Set LIB = C:\TDM-GCC-64\lib;;C:\TDM-GCC-64\lib;;
Set MW_TARGET_ARCH = win64;win64;
Set LIBPATH = C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\lib\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\lib\win64;
Options file details
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    Compiler location: C:\TDM-GCC-64
    Options file: C:\Users\myName\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2016b\mex_C++_win64.xml
    CMDLINE2 : C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\g++ -m64 -Wl,--no-undefined -shared -s -Wl,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/exportsmexfileversion.def" C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Temp\2\mex_53351148310745_8852\myTargetMex.obj C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Temp\2\mex_53351148310745_8852\cpp_mexapi_version.obj myclass.o (a few other .o files here) cpp_mexapi_version.o  -L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -llibmx -llibmex -llibmat -lm -llibmwlapack -llibmwblas -o myTargetMex.mexw64
    CXX : C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\g++
    COMPILER : C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\g++
    DEFINES : -DMX_COMPAT_32   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE
    MATLABMEX : -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE
    CXXFLAGS : -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11
    INCLUDE : -IC:\ourLibraryLocation  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/simulink/include"
    CXXOPTIMFLAGS : -O -DNDEBUG
    CXXDEBUGFLAGS : -g
    LDXX : C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\g++
    LINKER : C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\g++
    LDFLAGS : -m64 -Wl,--no-undefined
    LDTYPE : -shared
    LINKEXPORT : -Wl,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/mexFunction.def"
    LINKEXPORTVER : -Wl,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/exportsmexfileversion.def"
    LIBLOC : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\lib\win64\mingw64
    LINKLIBS : -L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -llibmx -llibmex -llibmat -lm -llibmwlapack -llibmwblas
    LDOPTIMFLAGS : -s
    LDDEBUGFLAGS : -g
    OBJEXT : .obj
    LDEXT : .mexw64
    SETENV : set COMPILER=g++
                set COMPFLAGS=-c -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -DMX_COMPAT_32   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE
                set OPTIMFLAGS=-O -DNDEBUG
                set DEBUGFLAGS=-g
                set LINKER=g++
                set LINKFLAGS=-m64 -Wl,--no-undefined -shared -L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -llibmx -llibmex -llibmat -lm -llibmwlapack -llibmwblas -Wl,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/mexFunction.def"
                set LINKDEBUGFLAGS=-g
                set NAME_OUTPUT= -o "%OUTDIR%%MEX_NAME%%MEX_EXT%"
    MINGWROOT : C:\TDM-GCC-64
    MATLABROOT : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b
    ARCH : win64
    SRC : C:\Users\myName\Desktop\test\myTargetMex.cpp;"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\version\cpp_mexapi_version.cpp"
    OBJ : C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Temp\2\mex_53351148310745_8852\myTargetMex.obj;C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Temp\2\mex_53351148310745_8852\cpp_mexapi_version.obj
    OBJS : C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Temp\2\mex_53351148310745_8852\myTargetMex.obj C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Temp\2\mex_53351148310745_8852\cpp_mexapi_version.obj myclass.o (a few other .o files here) cpp_mexapi_version.o
    SRCROOT : C:\Users\myName\Desktop\test\myTargetMex
    DEF : C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Temp\2\mex_53351148310745_8852\myTargetMex.def
    EXP : myTargetMex.exp
    LIB : myTargetMex.lib
    EXE : myTargetMex.mexw64
    ILK : myTargetMex.ilk
    MANIFEST : myTargetMex.mexw64.manifest
    TEMPNAME : myTargetMex
    EXEDIR :
    EXENAME : myTargetMex
    COMPFLAGS :  -std=c++03
    OPTIM : -O -DNDEBUG
    LINKOPTIM : -s
    CMDLINE1_0 : C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\g++ -c -DMX_COMPAT_32   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -IC:\ourLibraryLocation  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -O -DNDEBUG C:\Users\myName\Desktop\test\myTargetMex.cpp -o C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Temp\2\mex_53351148310745_8852\myTargetMex.obj
    CMDLINE1_1 : C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\g++ -c -DMX_COMPAT_32   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -IC:\ourLibraryLocation  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -O -DNDEBUG "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\version\cpp_mexapi_version.cpp" -o C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Temp\2\mex_53351148310745_8852\cpp_mexapi_version.obj
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'.
C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\g++ -c -DMX_COMPAT_32   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -IC:\ourLibraryLocation  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -O -DNDEBUG C:\Users\myName\Desktop\test\myTargetMex.cpp -o C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Temp\2\mex_53351148310745_8852\myTargetMex.obj
C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\g++ -c -DMX_COMPAT_32   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -IC:\ourLibraryLocation  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -O -DNDEBUG "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\version\cpp_mexapi_version.cpp" -o C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Temp\2\mex_53351148310745_8852\cpp_mexapi_version.obj
C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\g++ -m64 -Wl,--no-undefined -shared -s -Wl,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/exportsmexfileversion.def" C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Temp\2\mex_53351148310745_8852\myTargetMex.obj C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Temp\2\mex_53351148310745_8852\cpp_mexapi_version.obj myclass.o (a few other .o files here) cpp_mexapi_version.o  -L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -llibmx -llibmex -llibmat -lm -llibmwlapack -llibmwblas -o myTargetMex.mexw64
```

To be clear, MyClass is just another class included into myTargetMex. It just so happens to be the first one, so it naturally is the first thing to fail when the compilation is attempted. (As far as I know)

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: `-std=c++03` on the command line does not seem to jive well with `std::__cxx11::basic_string` in some of the error messages and the `-std=c++11` later in the build output. Poor tool chain may be getting confused.

Comment: That's definitely what I think, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Our code doesn't include anything from C++11. The lines it's getting confused about are both just ```std::ostringstream s;```. The thing is, this issue actually occured before I put the ```c++03``` flag in. That was my attempt to fix it, but clearly it manages to set it to C++11 regardless.

Comment: Your first error will go away if you remove `cpp_mexapi_version.o` from the `mex` command. Let `mex` figure out what it needs to do to compile your file, just give it your file plus whatever non-MATLAB libraries you explicitly use.

Comment: @CrisLuengo That took care of that issue. Much thanks! Any thoughts on the issue where ```COMPFLAGS='$COMPFLAGS -std=c++03'``` doesn't seem to be doing anything?

Comment: As a sidenote, I'd like to know more about ```cpp_mexapi_version``` at some point. I'm curious how we were using it when working manually, as opposed to what ```mex``` is doing. But that's a sidetrack and not immediately important to fixing the remaining issues.

Comment: `mex` adds that file in. By adding it manually, you add it twice, getting duplicate symbols. When compiling a MEX-file without using the `mex` command you need to do a lot of extra stuff that the `mex` command does for you.

Comment: Try setting `CXXFLAGS` instead?

Comment: @CrisLuengo That seems to have changed it correctly. The wiki suggested that in the MATLAB prompt COMPFLAGS should be used instead, but maybe I misunderstood it. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to have fixed those errors. How odd. It's still throwing undefined references to C++11 methods.

Comment: Does the verbose output of the mex command now show correct `CXXFLAGS`? It has `-std=c++11` in the output you have there currently. Maybe also add the strict flag?

Comment: Nevermind! It seems to be working again. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo Well, maybe not quite. It does work, though it has this in the arguments: ```-fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -std=c++03 -O```. Odd, but...it works. I'll take it.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I follow what's happening. The way I'm writing to CXXFLAGS is just adding on an additional flag. I can directly write out its contents rather than adding to it.

Comment: Indeed, you can do that. In any case, the last of the standard flags is the one that counts. Flags are read in order and the later ones overwrite the earlier ones if contradicting.

Comment: @CrisLuengo There is one final thing. Is there any way to do a more "makefile-esque" build using a MATLAB script? IE, right now if I want to make changes to CXXFLAGS and CXXOPTIMFLAGS I need to change the line that compiles each MEX file. Any way to set those in advance rather than at the line MEX is called?

Comment: You can do `mex(arg1,arg2,...)` with `arg1` and `arg2` variables that contain a string. Each string is one of the input arguments to the `mex` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what it came down to:

1. I needed to use $CXXFLAGS instead of $COMPFLAGS (the verbose output shows that COMPFLAGS never shows up here, but CXXFLAGS does)
2. Doing `CXXFLAGS='$CXXFLAGS -std=c++03'` just **adds** flags to the existing set of flags. (Duh, but I missed this) The existing set of flags, by default, includes `-std=c++11`. Technically, the last one just over-writes the old one, but that's still odd-looking. The better way is to do: `CXXFLAGS='-fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++03'`, so I include all the stuff it already had, but just replaced the c++ standard part. You can do the same with anything you want to change. Like `CXXOPTIMFLAGS='-O0 -DNDEBUG'` will just replace `-O` with `-O0`
3. As a sidenote: If your project has mixed C and CPP, that's messy. Just do yourself a favor and change all your .C files to .CPP. We had that, and when MEX tried to compile the .C files, it used GCC instead of G++ and had a hissy fit. Better to avoid that. As a reminder, the old mexFunction() entry point works *perfectly fine* in .C files. **mexFunction() does not need to be in a .C file!**

Many thanks to [Cris Luengo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7328782/cris-luengo) who has once again saved me with his MATLAB and MEX-file knowledge. :) I would've marked his solution as answer if he had put one up.